# javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider change BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY dynamyc

Tags: java, unix, soap, jax-ws

I have a jar in unix environment crontab. It`s call from crontab, there are a set of client JAX-ws classes. I need change BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY that have by default.

When I execute in my local environment that change endpoint for wsdl and create an consume al services, but In unix environment don´t change endpoint dynamyc.

What is happening there? or What can I do as workaround?

thank you!

```
        //String uriService= "http://prdtestte.dom:8220/Service?wsdl";
        String uriService = "http://devtestte.dom:8220/Service?wsdl";
        GeneratorWSService service = new GeneratorWSService();
        GeneratorWS port = service.getGeneratorWSPort();
        System.out.println("Port got it");
        //BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)port;
        configurePortBinding((BindingProvider)port, uriService);
        System.out.println("build port to URI "+((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext()
        .get(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY));
        Type queryType= port.queryType(10L);
        System.out.println("queryType name"+queryType.getName());
        System.exit(0);
```